# Self-referencing a table for a foreign key relationship in Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this problem but I haven't been able to find it or think it. I have a model "Entry" which are supposed to be in sequence with each other (For instance entry 1 might be the first part of a blog post, entry 2 the second part and so on)

```
class Entry(db.Model):
        __tablename__="entry"
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
                ...

        prev_entry_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entry.id'))
        next_entry_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('entry.id'))
        prev_entry = db.relationship("Entry", backref='next', remote_side='entry.id', foreign_keys=[prev_entry_id])  #previous_entry object
        next_entry = db.relationship("Entry",  backref="previous", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[next_entry_id])  #next_entry object
```

The idea is if you get one entry, say entry-56 you can navigate forward (57) and backward (55), step-by-step, all the way through, as if it were a pointer.

However I'm getting a ton of errors from sqlalchemy:

```
Table has no attribute 'id'
```

If I comment out "prev_entry" I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Entry->entry'. Original exception was: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'
```

If I comment out both "next_*entry" I get: `Table has no attribute 'id'`

If I comment out both "next_entry"* and "prev_entry" it at least loads.

In short, does anyone know the correct way to set this up in Flask-SqlAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no attribute id" error occurs because SQLAlchemy interprets `'entry.id'` as referring to the underlying `Table` object, rather than the model.  Fix this by using either `'Entry.id'` (model reference) or `'entry.c.id'` (table reference).

Additionally, use `back_populates` rather than `backref` to configure the reverse relationships:

```py
prev_entry = db.relationship(
    'Entry',
    back_populates='next_entry',
    remote_side='Entry.id',
    foreign_keys=[prev_entry_id],
)  # previous_entry object
next_entry = db.relationship(
    'Entry',
    back_populates='prev_entry',
    uselist=False,
    foreign_keys=[next_entry_id],
)  # next_entry object
```